# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, header, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to access an external API, but I always get the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/rankings/character/porkiz/blackmoore/EU?metric=dps&limit=5000&api_key=xxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have found many questions on this topic, but couldn't find a solution. Obviously, I don't have access to the server, so I can't modify anything there. Apparantly, the API also doesn't support JSONP.

However, I could make it work by installing the CORS extension in Google Chrome. Any idea on how to solve the problem without any external extensions? I'm using a simple AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {
                _processData(result);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Make the request to a server you control which makes the request to the service on the clients behalf.

Comment: Do you have any simple example or tutorial or something like that for me? I'm pretty new at JS :)

Comment: Unless you want to create a server script with JS, this has nothing to do with JS. Create a proxy service with whichever language you like and and make the request to that service instead to `https://www.warcraftlogs.com/`. If you don't want to write your own, there are prebuilt solutions, e.g. for Node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/corsproxy.